# How to display route beteen two latitude and longitude with custom name?

Tags: iphone

I have implemented one dating application in which I have open iPhone map application with source and destination latitude and longitude.But when i touch on the drop pin it display unkown road.But I want to display like user1 and user2 on drop pin.

Please help me for this query

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to display on the drop pin's pop up right?

Comment: Yes but on map iphone default application from my application

Answer (score 0):

In your View Controller in which you're implementing MapView, you must be implementing MapView's delegate method, viewForAnnotation!!!

Implement it like this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    MKAnnotationView * annotationView = nil;    
    [mapLoadingIndicatorView stopAnimating];

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        [self.mapView.userLocation setTitle:@"User1"];
        return annotationView;
    }

    annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentAnnotation"];

    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

    return annotationView;

}
```

And also make sure you've made an AddressAnnotation Class in which

AddressAnnotation.h

```
@interface AddressAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString * title_;
    NSString * subtitle_;

}

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D     coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString  * title_;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString  * subtitle_;

@end
```

And AddressAnnotation.m:

```
@implementation AddressAnnotation

@synthesize coordinate, title_, subtitle_;

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c: (NSString *)title: (NSString *)subtitle {

    if ((self = [super init])) {

        coordinate= c ;
        self.title_ = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", title];
        self.subtitle_ = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", subtitle];
        NSLog(@"title_%@", self.title_);
        NSLog(@"subtitle_%@", self.subtitle_);

        //self.title_ = @"Title";
        //self.subtitle_ = @"Subtitle";



    }
    return self;
}

- (NSString *)title {
    return self.title_;
}

- (NSString *)subtitle {
    return self.subtitle_;
}

@end
```

Comment: I am passing two lat,long and open map iphone default application.

Comment: If you are opening the iPhone's default Map application, then you can not display custom user names in that... For that you must create your application's own MapViewController...